# Makefile: process colon-separated environment variables

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

Say I have some environment variable like

```
echo $CPATH
/share/software/user/open/metis/5.1.0/include:/share/software/user/restricted/imkl/2018/mkl/include
```

How I can use that within a Makefile where I'm compiling code with gcc (or whatever)? 
This doesn't seem to work

```
gcc -I$(CPATH)
```

as gcc can't seem to process those.

What is the preferred solution? Should I just c/p the path inside my Makefile or is something else more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GNU make I think the following is a simple (and maybe elegant) solution:

```
gcc -I $(subst :, -I ,${CPATH})
```

The case of BSD make:

```
gcc -I ${CPATH:C,:, -I ,g}
```

And maybe you can use `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable too:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=${CPATH} ; gcc ...
```